# Fatal error: Call to undefined function - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i get this error i dont know why.

i have a function that produce random characters

```
function randomString($length) {
        $len = $length;
        $base = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTWXYZabcdefghıjklmnoprstwxyz123456789';
        $max = strlen($base) - 1;
        $activatecode = '';
        mt_srand((double) microtime() * 1000000);
        while (strlen($activatecode) < $len + 1)
            $activatecode.=$base(mt_rand(0, $max));

        return activatecode;
    }
```

and i call this function in

```
public function kayitBasarili() {
        $this->load->view('kayitBasarili');

        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $email = $this->input->post('email');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $data = array();

        $data['username'] = $username;
        $data['email'] = $email;
        $data['password'] = $password;

        **$activationCode = $this->randomString(10);** 

        $this->load->view('kayitBasarili', $data);
        $this->kayitmodel->uyeEkle($username, $email, $password,$activationCode);
    }
```

Why i get this error ? 
[image]

Comment: whats with the `**` surrounding the function? pretty sure that would cause issues

Comment: it is bold function but does not work in code view :)

Comment: Mert, you still need to return `$activatecode`.  :-) And why not just use `substr( md5( microtime() . 'somesalt' ), 0, 10)`?

Comment: is it necessary to use md5 for activationcode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at this line:

```
$activatecode.=$base(mt_rand(0, $max)); // Your calling the string as a function
```

it should be:

```
$activatecode.=$base{mt_rand(0, $max)};
```

or

```
$activatecode.=$base[mt_rand(0, $max)];
```

Comment: From the PHP manual "**Note**: Strings may also be accessed using braces, as in $str{42}, for the same purpose. However, this syntax is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0. Use square brackets instead, such as $str[42]."

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
$activatecode.=$base(mt_rand(0, $max));
```

calls the function whose name is the contents of `$base` = `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTWXYZabcdefghıjklmnoprstwxyz123456789'`hence the error;

Comment: BTW, the index operator is `[]` not `()` and you need to return `$activatecode` (with the `$`).